# ibeacon connectable transmission mode

Tags: ios, bluetooth, ibeacon

I recently bought an ibeacon from socialRetail with the specifications mentioning 'connectable and non-connectable transmission mode' as supported:

http://www.ibeaconstore.com/ibeacon-water-resistant-silicone

From the definition of connectable mode for beacons given in the following Texas instrument doc:

'The connectable beacon is a Bluetooth low energy device in peripheral mode, which means that it cannot only transmit, but also receive as well.'

(Source: http://www.ti.com.cn/cn/lit/an/swra475/swra475.pdf), this iBeacon should be capable of transmitting and receiving messages.

Now, iBeacon (not configured on an iDevice, just a standalone iBeacon like the one I bought) is supposed to be a transmit-only (or broadcast) device. So, what exactly does the 'connectable transmission mode' imply here? Can I somehow use this standalone iBeacon device to work in a half/full duplex mode?

Comment: A iBeacon shouldn't be by definition connectable, it only broadcasts, but I guess that is a mode where you can do the settings for it in BLE only (not necessary through a cable, like changing its Major/Minor, UUID).

Comment: Sounds to me like the device is a hybrid, operating as both an iBeacon and as a regular BLE device.

Answer (score 1):

**Beacons should typically broadcast non-connectable advertisements** as they are transmit only devices as you say.  However, **many vendors allow them to be configured** by a Bluetooth connection.  Establishing this connection **requires devices seeing a connectable advertisement**, so vendors can either send a second advertisement or modify the beacon advertisement to be connectable (even if this violates the spec.)

Because connectable adverts can case mobile devices to process them differently and in a less ideal way than non-connectable ones (some Android devices can receive only one connectable advertisement per Bluetooth scan), **sending connectable advertisements should be avoided**.  For this reason, many beacon vendors have ways of switching this behavior.